# Best way to run J-Meter test's from jenkins

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, jmeter

What I want to achieve is as:

1. Build the maven project and push the jar to repo, using maven & jenkins.
2. Deploy the application, using script.
3. Run jmeter test cases and display test results in jenkins dashboard.

First jenkins build my project and push it to repo.
Then I have defined a post build step in jenkins to run script on remote server, this script deploys and starts my application.

Then I have created a post build action in jenkins to invoke top-level maven targets, to run mvn verify, which triggers the jmeter-maven plugin, which runs the test cases on my already running application.

Is this a good approach and if not please let me know a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The bit that may be missing here is how Jenkins knows if the build should be marked as passed or failed? Even if jmeter-maven-analysis plugin execution did exit with zero exit code, it doesn't mean performance-wise the application is fine. It may be, but don't have to be. I came across that kind of concerns some time ago and provided a [solution](https://github.com/automatictester/lightning). Check project [wiki](https://github.com/automatictester/lightning/wiki/Usage-Example) for usage example and more information.